# Graph implementation , using adjacency matrix , With custom data in links

Tags: c++, graph

I want to have some custom data in my links. consider stLINK is some struct , which presents the link data. One way is to put pointer of such struct , in matrix (as int , casting needed), another way is to create a vector of links , and put the index of each link item in the matrix. please help me if there is a standard way. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you need to have custom data for each edge, right? I use a vector and a map to do this.

```
struct data_t { 
 // any data you want to store for an edge
 int a,b,c; 
 string name;
};

std::vector< std::map<int, data_t> > adj;
```

This way it is faster to check whether an edge exists. Otherwise you can just use `std::vector<data_t>`

Answer (score 0):

You have not described what “custom data” and “links” are. I’ll assume they’re classes. You should make a class if something (here “links”) should carry several types of data at once. Of course you can make a matrix of objects in C++, no need to cast to `int`.

1. If your “custom data” can live for the whole time as a “link” does and each link has its own “custom data”, the easiest way is to add the data into the class Link.

   ```
   class Link
   {
       customData_t data;
       // other useful attributes (and methods)
   };
   ```
2. You can create a [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) of your “custom data”. It will manage creation and deletion of items. The fastest way to access a random element is to know its position in memory – a pointer. I see no need for any cast to int.

   ```
   std::vector<customData_t> CustomData;

   class Link
   {    
       customData_t* data;
       // other useful attributes (and methods)
   };
   ```

   Filling `data`:

   ```
   Link l;
   customData_t temp;
   CustomData.push_back(temp);
   l.data = &(CustomData.back());
   ```

   (Or you could use `vector::emplace_back()` in C++11.)

   Accessing is easy: `*l.data`

   This way is better if you want to share the same data across several “links” or if they should be added/removed during the life of a “link”.